# How update a single file installed in the APK while developing an app on Android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, apk, adb

I am developing an Android application that has a NDK `.so` file which I need to iterate on and fix + improve.

The current workflow has me having to generate a APK and install it every iteration which updates a whole plethora of non NDK elements in the process really slowing things down.

The question is how could I access the installation folder of my own APK? I have both a rooted and unrooted device.

Is there some change I could make to install the app in an unprotected location for development purposes even. The installation data is my own application after all so feels like should be a way...

Help greatly appreciated :)

EDIT1:
I found `Unity3D` has some sort of patching mode, maybe this is a sign that with the correct ADB commands it may be possible... https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-AppPatching.html

EDIT2: I found the location of the `.so` I am building in... checked on unrooted device and don't have permission.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your app is not a native-only app (has a Java/Kotlin part) then your so library should be loaded at the moment using a call to [System.loadlibrary(..)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System#loadLibrary(java.lang.String)).

What is interesting on this method is, that calls to this method are ignored if the library to be loaded has already been loaded. So if you modify the Java code of the development build of your app to manually load your library before the original loadLibrary call is executed you can end up with a different library loaded.

The only problem is that `System.loadLibrary(..)` does not accept a file-name or path as argument. But using [System.load(..)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System#load(java.lang.String)) which uses a full path as argument you should be able to specify a full path to a file e.g. in the app's data directory. That way you can replace the library as often as you want and then just restart the app to load the updated library.

Comment: Sounds like this could work and extend to my situation. I should elaborate that the project is actually a Unity3D build so it is essentially Native only I guess (C#, C++, + Assets). However adding a Java module should be viable and if I were to call that first which in-turn calls `System.load(...)` your workaround could be a good one!